# Shinydashboard isn't rendering the UI properly on AWS Shiny-Server

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

When I run the following `app.R` file everything works perfectly.

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

      box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It looks like this:
[image]

However, when I deploy it to my `shiny-server` running on an AWS instance, it doesn't render properly. I think it must be something with `shinydashboard` because I have other shiny apps running on the server and they work just fine. The only apps that have this issue are apps that I'm trying to deploy that use `shinydashboard`. It is installed on the server, so I'm not sure what I could be missing. Here is what it looks like on the server:
[image]

EDIT:: 
It also seems to work perfectly on `shinyapps.io`. So it must be something with my AWS Ubuntu server and `shinydashboard`. I have it installed and its `‘0.7.1’` package version. What could this be?

There is nothing in the shiny-server logs. Here is the app-log
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the server/application logs?

```
/var/log/shiny-server.log
/var/log/shiny-server/*.log
```

I think the Histogram box should be rendering as well unless a parenthesis/comma is missing?

Comment: there is nothing in the server logs, and i'll show what the application log shows as part of an edit

maybe i need to just install and reinstall?